# How to build sqlheavy 0-2?

Tags: ubuntu, autotools

I am trying to build [sqlheavy 0-2](https://gitorious.org/sqlheavy/sqlheavy) on **Ubuntu trusty** as there is no ppa for 0-2

The `INSTALL` file is outdated and I am not an autotools ninja.

So far, I did:

```
git clone https://git.gitorious.org/sqlheavy/sqlheavy.git
# Because some text are required for some reason
touch NEWS README AUTHORS ChangeLog
automake --add-missing
```

And I run into the following errors (and warnings):

```
examples/Makefile.am:34: warning: 'INCLUDES' is the old name for 'AM_CPPFLAGS' (or '*_CPPFLAGS')
examples/Makefile.am:24: warning: 'VALAFLAGS' is a user variable, you should not override it;
examples/Makefile.am:24: use 'AM_VALAFLAGS' instead
examples/Makefile.am:11: warning: variable 'GTK_LDFLAGS' is defined but no program or
examples/Makefile.am:11: library has 'GTK' as canonical name (possible typo)
gtk/Makefile.am:3: error: Libtool library used but 'LIBTOOL' is undefined
gtk/Makefile.am:3:   The usual way to define 'LIBTOOL' is to add 'LT_INIT'
gtk/Makefile.am:3:   to 'configure.ac' and run 'aclocal' and 'autoconf' again.
gtk/Makefile.am:3:   If 'LT_INIT' is in 'configure.ac', make sure
gtk/Makefile.am:3:   its definition is in aclocal's search path.
sqlheavy/Makefile.am:115: warning: '%'-style pattern rules are a GNU make extension
sqlheavy/Makefile.am:116: warning: LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH: non-POSIX variable name
sqlheavy/Makefile.am:5: error: Libtool library used but 'LIBTOOL' is undefined
sqlheavy/Makefile.am:5:   The usual way to define 'LIBTOOL' is to add 'LT_INIT'
sqlheavy/Makefile.am:5:   to 'configure.ac' and run 'aclocal' and 'autoconf' again.
sqlheavy/Makefile.am:5:   If 'LT_INIT' is in 'configure.ac', make sure
sqlheavy/Makefile.am:5:   its definition is in aclocal's search path.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed the `autogen.sh` file :

```
clone git git://gitorious.org/sqlheavy/sqlheavy.git
./autogen.sh
sudo make install
```

On to the next error!